# How to properly exchange symmetric aes key using RSA

Tags: c++, openssl, aes, rsa

Im trying to implement ssl handshake in c++ using OpenSSL library
(in context, because nodes are communicating through gateway, so I cant use already implemented ssl sockets)

Lets have sender and receiver

1. Sender sends his certificate to receiver
2. Receiver creates AES key from senders pub_key (contained in certificate)
3. Receiver encrypts AES key with senders pub_key and then with its private key and sends it to Sender (together with its certificate)
4. Sender decrypts it with receivers pub_key and then with its private key

public encrypt with RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
private encrypt with RSA_NO_PADDING

Now the private decrypt part fails about 50% of time with

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02
```

And I have no idea how to fix that.

Whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/evp.h"
#include "openssl/aes.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include <openssl/pem.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int ret = 0;

  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

  srand(time(NULL));

  X509 *sender_x, *receiver_x;
  RSA *sender_priv_key, *sender_pub_key, *receiver_priv_key, *receiver_pub_key;
  EVP_PKEY *sender_evp_key, *receiver_evp_key;

  string sender_ssl_cert = "unit_test/ini/00000000000Wcert.pem";
  string sender_ssl_key = "unit_test/ini/00000000000Wkey.pem";
  string receiver_ssl_cert = "unit_test/ini/00000000000Rcert.pem";
  string receiver_ssl_key = "unit_test/ini/00000000000Rkey.pem";
  string ssl_ca="unit_test/ini/sitsroot.pem";
  BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    unsigned char tmp_buf[2000 + 1];

    unsigned char key[32], iv[32];

    /** **************************************************************** */
    /** ************************ READ FILES **************************** */
    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen(sender_ssl_cert.c_str(), "r")) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to open file " << sender_ssl_cert << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    if ((sender_x = PEM_read_X509(f, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to read cert file " << sender_ssl_cert << endl;
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }
    fclose(f);

    if ((f = fopen(sender_ssl_key.c_str(), "r")) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to open file " << sender_ssl_key << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    if ((sender_priv_key = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(f, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to read cert file " << sender_ssl_key << endl;
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }
    fclose(f);

    if ((f = fopen(receiver_ssl_cert.c_str(), "r")) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to open file " << receiver_ssl_cert << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    if ((receiver_x = PEM_read_X509(f, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to read cert file " << receiver_ssl_cert << endl;
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }
    fclose(f);

    if ((f = fopen(receiver_ssl_key.c_str(), "r")) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to open file " << receiver_ssl_key << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    if ((receiver_priv_key = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(f, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL) {
      cout << "failed to read cert file " << receiver_ssl_key << endl;
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }
    fclose(f);
    /** ************************ READ FILES **************************** */
    /** **************************************************************** */

    /** **************************************************************** */
    /** *********************** GENERATE KEY *************************** */
    sender_evp_key = X509_get_pubkey(sender_x);

    PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio, sender_evp_key);

    ret = BIO_read(bio, tmp_buf, 2000);

    ret = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), NULL, tmp_buf, ret, 5, key, iv);
    if (ret != 32) {
      cout << "Key size is " << ret << " bytes, should be 256 bits" << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    /** *********************** GENERATE KEY *************************** */
    /** **************************************************************** */

    /** **************************************************************** */
    /** *********************** ENCRYPT KEY **************************** */
    sender_pub_key = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(sender_evp_key);

    unsigned char *encrypted_key = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(sender_pub_key) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if ((ret = RSA_public_encrypt(32, key, encrypted_key, sender_pub_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) < 0) {
      cout << "RSA_public_encrypt failed: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << endl;
      return -1;
    }

    if ((ret = RSA_private_encrypt(ret, encrypted_key, encrypted_key, receiver_priv_key, RSA_NO_PADDING)) < 0) {
      cout << "RSA_private_encrypt failed, " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << endl;
      return -1;
    }

    cout << "RSA_private_encrypt ret: " << ret << endl;
    /** *********************** ENCRYPT KEY **************************** */
    /** **************************************************************** */

    /** **************************************************************** */
    /** *********************** DECRYPT KEY **************************** */
    if ((receiver_evp_key = X509_get_pubkey(receiver_x)) == NULL) cout << "receiver_evp_key NULL" << endl;
    if ((receiver_pub_key = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(receiver_evp_key)) == NULL) cout << "receiver_pub_key NULL" << endl;

    unsigned char *decrypted_key = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(receiver_pub_key) * sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
    if ((ret = RSA_public_decrypt(ret, encrypted_key, decrypted_key, receiver_pub_key, RSA_NO_PADDING)) < 0) {
      cout << "RSA_public_decrypt failed, " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    cout << "RSA_public_decrypt ret: " << ret << endl;

    if ((ret = RSA_private_decrypt(ret, decrypted_key, decrypted_key, sender_priv_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) < 0) {
      cout << "RSA_private_decrypt failed, " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    cout << "RSA_private_decrypt ret: " << ret << endl;

    /** *********************** DECRYPT KEY **************************** */
    /** **************************************************************** */

    return 0;
  }
```

Edit:
That turned to be okey after changing strlen to ret value returned by encrypt function
But lets go to the step 3.
Adding this code to the end (just before return 0; statement)

```
  /** **************************************************************** */
  /** ******************* ANOTHER ENCRYPT KEY ************************ */
  unsigned char *another_encrypted_key = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(receiver_pub_key) * sizeof(unsigned char));
  if ((ret = RSA_public_encrypt(32, decrypted_key, another_encrypted_key, receiver_pub_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)) < 0) {
    cout << "RSA_public_encrypt failed: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  if ((ret = RSA_private_encrypt(ret, another_encrypted_key, another_encrypted_key, sender_priv_key, RSA_NO_PADDING)) < 0) {
    cout << "RSA_private_encrypt failed, " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  /** ******************* ANOTHER ENCRYPT KEY ************************ */
  /** **************************************************************** */
```

this results in about 15% chance of getting:

```
error:04066084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_ENCRYPT:data too large for modulus
```

on RSA_private_encrypt
and this is the main issue Im struggling with (the one before was just my mistake)

Edit2:

```
RSA_public_encrypt ret: 128
RSA_size(sender_priv_key): 128
RSA_private_encrypt failed, error:04066084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_ENCRYPT:data too large for modulus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code misuses `strlen`. The `strlen` function can only be used on C-style strings, not on arbitrary binary data.

The documentation states that `RSA_private_encrypt` and `RSA_private_decrypt` return the length of the encrypted/decrypted data. But you call `strlen` on `encrypted_key` which is *not* a C-style string -- it's just a block of arbitrary binary data with no simple structure.

You don't need to call `strlen` on it because `RSA_private_encrypt` returns its length. And you *can't* call `strlen` on it because it's not a string.

A lot of people have mistaken impressions about what `strlen` (and sometimes `sizeof`) do. They have precisely defined semantics that you must understand in order to properly use those functions. They do not magically determine how big an arbitrary data structure is. If you don't specifically know that something is a C-style string, do not pass it to any of the `str*` functions.

Think about it -- what algorithm could `strlen` possibly implement that would be able to determine the length of a block of encrypted data just by looking at a pointer to the first byte of that data? You are expecting magic.

Comment: Oh my bad, it's just that I was just comparing values of return value from private encrypt and strlen, and in like first 3-4 runs it was the same value, so I assumed that it was null terminating the string

Comment: Most likely the buffer started out filled with zeroes and by sheer luck there just didn't happen to be a zero in the encrypted data. The fact that you had to cast should have been a give away though -- who stores C-style strings in `unsigned char *` so that you have to cast any time you want to pass them to a `str*` function? That wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: editet my answer, adding more code that fails on something else, actualy encrypting the decrypted key again

Comment: The "data too large for modulus" error means that you're trying to encrypt data that's larger than your RSA key's size. Most likely you should encrypt a random fixed-length key and use that to encrypt the decrypted key with a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: I added som debug output, but return value from public encrypt is same as size of private key

Comment: @Pinker: If you have a typical 15-digit number and you take a random 15-digit number, either one can be larger. So it's not surprising this fails some of the time. (Perhaps you should step back and reconsider whether what you're dong makes sense.)

Comment: Is there then some other way how to do this? Im open to suggestions. But this ssl handshake model was taken from wikipedia, so it should somehow work. I just need to somehow (securely) exchange 32-byte string between two nodes.

Comment: Does the client already know the server's public key? Or are you only trying to be secure against passive interception? Why not use SSL? Why doesn't the client just generate a random AES key and encrypt it with the server's public key and send that?

Comment: I was told that encrypting it with both public key and signing it with its private key is more secure, especially against third party.

Comment: @Pinker: It depends no what your threat model is. Generally, we assume the server doesn't care who or what it gets the string from. If the client has a public key that the server knows, then things do get more complicated. (Again, why not just use SSL?)

Comment: Because there is one gateway connecting multiple nodes, using ssl sockets I would get encrypt->decrypt->encrypt->decrypt, thats how its implemented today, but thats just too much overhead. Guess we will have to rework that handshake somehow. Thank you for your time and help.